# button action in gridview

Tags: android, button, gridview, onclicklistener

I have a gridview with a delete button in each grid item. My code is as follows:

### MainActivity

...`generate_photos()` ...

```
gd_view.setAdapter(new SampleGridViewAdapter(Photos.this));
                gd_view.setOnScrollListener(new SampleScrollListener(Photos.this));
                gd_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
                    {
                        Utilities.custom_toast(Photos.this, "View big", ""+position, "short");
                    }
                });
                gd_view.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
                {
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                    {
                        //Utilities.custom_toast(Photos.this, "LONG Press", ""+position, "short");
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

### Adapter

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        gridView =new View(context);

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview, null);

        ImageView btn_delete = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        ImageView img_grid = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid);
        final TextView tv_ref = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ref);

        final String url = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(img_grid);
        tv_ref.setText(""+id.get(position));

        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(tv_ref.getText().toString());
                Records_Photo n = Select.from(Records_Photo.class).where(Condition.prop("photo_Id").eq(id)).first();
                n.delete();
            }
        });

        return gridView;
```

### Question:

After pressing the delete button, I would like the gridview to refresh such that to make the picture deleted disappeared from the gridview. I am trying to call `MainActivity.generate_photo(); to refresh but it said`non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`

So how to refresh the gridview after pressing the delete button? It seems it is a loop now.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you remove the Records_Photo object from the Adapter's list and refreshed using `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: did you tried notifyDataSetChanged() method

Comment: If you press the delete button, then close the application and open it again, do you get the desired result?

Comment: @H.Brooks: Yes, if close and re-open again, I get the desired result. ie. the gridview has removed the deleted photo properly

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method, after deletion of image?

Comment: yes, i have tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the button_delete `setOnClickListener` (the one inside the Adapter) but nothing happened. The list is not refreshed immediately. Or should I put at where?

Comment: This is not a answer and could've been posted in the comments section.